# Nhibernate Query where object model array intersects a C# array

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Imagine we have a mapped nhibernate object model called `User` which contains a list of `Registrations`. We also have a C# array that contains a list of valid registrations.

How can I query only the users that contains a valid registration?

I tried the following:

```
Registration[] validRegistrations; // already populated
session.Query<User>().Where(usr => usr.Registrations.Intersect(validRegistrations).Any());
```

When I try this, I get the following error: `"The IntersectResultOperator result operator is not current supported"`

Comment: are users and registration bi-diectionally mapped?  Can a user have an invalid registration?

Answer (score 2):

While not optimal, wouldn't something like this work?

```
var results = 
    session
        .Query<User>()
        .Where(usr => validRegistrations.Contains(usr.Registrations)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind switching to LINQ query syntax for this one (which I think makes it more readable), I believe you're looking for the following:

```
var results = from user in session.Query<User>()
              from registration in user.Registrations
              where validRegistrations.Contains(registration)
              select user;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is equivalent to an `Intersect`:

```
session.Query<User>().Where(usr => usr.Registrations.Any(reg => validRegistrations.Contains(reg)));
```